# How to use asp vbscript to add string items into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vbscript, autocomplete

According to jquery ui API, the source of an autocomplete field may be an array variable. How can I populate the array variable with results from a vbscript recordset result?

In the body of my page the I have my code something like this:

```
Dim rs, data_source
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.ActiveConnection = MM_rtasql_STRING
rs.CursorType = 2
rs.CursorLocation = 2
rs.LockType = 3

rs.source = "select field1 from mydatabase where whatever > soandso"
WHILE NOT rs.EOF
//add each result to string array JavaScript/Jquery can access.
```

I would like to pull the variable in my document ready function for my jquery auto complete field. How can this be implemented?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote the remote datasource. When using firefox with firebug I press F12 to open the console and see the xhr request made when I type something.

Inspecting the response I can see that JSON is used:

```
[{"id":"Turdus philomelos","label":"Song Thrush","value":"Song Thrush"},
 {"id":"Melospiza melodia","label":"Song Sparrow","value":"Song Sparrow"}
]
```

I think you can leave out the id because that would be optional. You could try an array of strings return like:

```
["Song Thrush","Song Sparrow"]
```

The vb code you're showing looks like server side code that would not run in a browser, the autocomplete will make a call to that asp page when the user types something and that is then used to filter your data:

The GET parameter that the autocomplete sends is called term. Look for the js code on the jquery ui page: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, assuming that you are happy populating the list on page load and don't want to do a lookup to the server in real-time:

```
<%
' server-side ASP
Dim rs, data_source, ado
Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
ado.ConnectionString = MM_rtasql_STRING
ado.Open
rs.ActiveConnection = ado
rs.CursorType = 2
rs.CursorLocation = 2
rs.LockType = 3

rs.Open "select field1 from mydatabase where whatever > soandso"

' build up a string which looks like a Javascipt array (eg "['val1','val2']")
' instead of a loop, you could use rs.GetString(), which is quicker
dim s: s = "["
do until rs.EOF
    s = s & "'" & CStr(rs("field1")) & "',"
loop
rs.Close
' remove trailing comma and complete array string
s = left(s, len(s) - 1) & "]"
%>
<!-- client-side -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
           $("textbox-selector").autocomplete({
                 source: <%=s %> // ASP insert of javascript array string
           });
     });
</script>
```

I've not tested this and the jQuery I've taken from their example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score -1):

How about using the push() method?

Comment: In the future, please provide more details in your answers.